# Strange addition

Tags: lateral-thinking

Professor Devonshire was losing his marbles, Dr. Wallaby thought, staring at the equations filling the board in Dr. Devonshire’s office. What kind of addition was this?

1+1 = 6

2+1 = 6

1+6 = 6

2+6 = 6

6+6 = 6

1+3 = 8

7+9 = ?

I wonder what goes in the blank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what goes in the blank is

> 9

Because

> the addition is of the number of letters in each one of the numbers to the left of the equal sign.

So

> one + one = 6 letters
>  two + one = 6 letters
>  one + six = 6 letters
>  two + six = 6 letters
>  six + six = 6 letters
>  one + three = 8 letters
>  and
>  seven + nine = 9 letters